# Passing name from input to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have an input:

Now this is one input from a div with several different inputs, there is a button called add exp which generates a new div with those inputs by calling href="#" and then jquery does the rest, only the name changes to for example institutionName0, institutionName1 etc so the fields get distinct. In my servlet I want to be able to get the actual input name like institutionName0 so I can check how much of the same fields are generated and that I can put in different values in those different fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your form values to Servlet as a jSon object using ajax.

```
//Example
function onSubmit(divName){
document.forms["formName"]["formName_currentAction"].value = divName;
var theForm = $("form[name=formName]"); 
var params = theForm.serialize(); 
$.ajax({     
type:"POST",     
url:actionURL,
cache: false,
data:params,     
success:function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        //do something here
},     
error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){        

        } 
   });
```